# Parsing JSON returns nil, why?

Tags: ios, json, swift

This is my first project working with JSON, so this question could probably be relevant to others in the same situation.
I'm making a weather app using the DarkSky API. So far, I'm requesting the data from the internet, parsing it and, for testing, printing it in the console. Unfortunately, I just get nil. Here's the relevant code:

-> Functions in my ViewController:

```
func getWeatherData(latitude: String, longitude: String, time: String) {

    let basePath = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxb170/"
    let url = basePath + "\(latitude),\(longitude)"
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
        (data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?)
        in

        if let data = data {
            do {
                if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:Any] {
                    let dictionary = json
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(dictionary, forKey: "lastWeatherUpdate")
                }
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)

            }

        }
    }


}

func getCurrentWeather() {
    getWeatherData(latitude: "37", longitude: "40", time: "40000")
    let weather = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "lastWeatherUpdate")

    print(weather?["latitude"])
}
```

Does someone spot my mistake? Here's how DarkSky specifies the structure of the JSON data:

```
"latitude": 47.20296790272209,
  "longitude": -123.41670367098749,
  "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "currently": {
    "time": 1453402675,
    "summary": "Rain",
    "icon": "rain",
    "nearestStormDistance": 0,
    "precipIntensity": 0.1685,
    "precipIntensityError": 0.0067,
    "precipProbability": 1,
    "precipType": "rain",
    "temperature": 48.71,
    "apparentTemperature": 46.93,
    "dewPoint": 47.7,
    "humidity": 0.96,
    "windSpeed": 4.64,
    "windGust": 9.86,
    "windBearing": 186,
    "visibility": 4.3,
    "cloudCover": 0.73,
    "pressure": 1009.7,
    "ozone": 328.35
```

Well, apparently that's just the important part of the JSON.

Can anyone spot my mistake?

Comment: `data` is nil or `json` is nil?

Comment: It's because the call is async. Also it's missing `task.resume()` Look for "Swift + Async + Closure" to get more info and solutions.

Comment: No, I just print out nil... Where would I have to add task.resume() in this code?

Comment: Part 3 of "Using an URL Session" from the doc: "Each task starts out in a suspended state. After your app calls resume on the task, it begins downloading the specified resource.". So you need to do `task.resume()` after your created it. Also, if you add a `print("closure callback of task")` just before `if let data {` you'll see that it will print AFTER `print(weather?["latitude"])`. So I as suggested, do the research on "Swift + Async + Closure" there are plenty of questions and answers about it, it's pretty basic.

Comment: @user8206035 you define a task in line let task = .... next, you have to resume it with task.resume() (next line after the definition), otherwise the task will not run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does someone spot my mistake?

Actually there are two mistakes:

- As mentioned in the comments the task must be `resumed`
- `dataTask` works asynchronously, it requires a completion handler to be able to print something after the call.

---

The code uses a simple enum with associated types as return type for convenience reasons.

```
enum WeatherResult {
    case success([String:Any]), failure(Error)
}

func getWeatherData(latitude: String, longitude: String, time: String, completion: @escaping (WeatherResult)->()) {

    let basePath = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxb170/"
    let urlString = basePath + "\(latitude),\(longitude)"
    let url = URL(string: urlString)!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        if let error = error {
           completion(.failure(error))
           return 
        }

        do {
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String:Any] {
                completion(.success(json))
            } else {
                completion(.failure(NSError(domain: "myDomain", code: 1, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "JSON is not a dictionary"])))
            }
        } catch {
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}

func getCurrentWeather() {
    getWeatherData(latitude: "37", longitude: "40", time: "40000") { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let dictionary):
            UserDefaults.standard.set(dictionary, forKey: "lastWeatherUpdate")
            print(dictionary["latitude"])
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```